# Debugger does not stop at breakpoints when running on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, xcode4

I want to test my app on device and see all the NSLOGs on console while runnig the ap on device.I also want to stop the app at breakpoints but app does not stop on breakpoints and not print NSLOGs .I have unchecked load symbols lazily .I am using a debug build .Please tell me how to achieve this 
Thanks in advance

NOTE:After starting the app x code shows the app being debugged is not being run (I think the problem is after xcode transfers the app to device then it disconnects with device)

Comment: after connecting the device click build and run option from the xcode.are you doing the same?

Comment: while testing on device check NSLog in window->Organizer->Device logs

Comment: Are you sure that the app is actually getting to your code that has the breakpoints and log statements?

Comment: @phillip:Yes app is working fine with all alerts etc

Comment: @efrank: Tried everything from build and debug to build and run etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set breakpoint in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions then the viewwillappear of the view you want to test the breakpoints on. basically any places before your code (which you want to test) which surely get called.

I had same problem before not exactly sure why does it happen though. 
it's like preparing Xcode to look for breakpoints :)

Comment: Then hard to say what exactly going on..give a try to restart everything... xcode if needed mac and iphone too.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have breakpoints enabled in xCode?

[image]

Should be looking like this;

[image]

Comment: THanks for the answer but thats an obvious thing

Comment: Just a quick note that this actually helped me - even though I had breakpoints enabled in Xcode, I found that toggling the option off and then back on again resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're working with a jailbroken device .. Is that the case ?
If you are , the "official" answer should be "disable mobileSubstrate addons".
I've managed to run the app in debug mode , after :

1. Doing what you mentioned (got that error message).
2. Double tap home-button , hold the app icon, close the app..
3. Run it again from XCode.
4. Repeat again if necessary.

Comment: @pankaj , not the app , the phone.

Comment: Okay. try these steps anyway please.. it worked for me (for a jailbroken device, but could work for you as well..)