# iPhone does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I have installed Xcode 4.3.3 on Max OsX Lion and now when I debug my application in the simulator in iOS 5.1.1 then it stops at breakpoints but when I debug on an iPhone device with iOS 5.1.1 then it does not stop on breakpoints.
I have no idea why it is not working properly. I have researched alot but did not get any solution. And my device is jailbroken and I updated its iOS from 3.1 to 5.1.1. please help me if anyone knows.

i have tried these links as a solution but no works in my case:

[Debugger does not stop at breakpoints when running on iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733284/debugger-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints-when-running-on-iphone-device)

[How to run the iphone app in xcode4 with breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925644/how-to-run-the-iphone-app-in-xcode4-with-breakpoints)

[iPhone Device Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983657/iphone-device-debugging)

Comment: what iPhone model do you have ?

Comment: just to verify, are you running the app on the device (selecting the device from the schema manager at the top left)?  and does the device show up in the Devices section of the Organizer?

Comment: Yes device is showing in organizer

Answer (score 0):

It must be a bug cause I had the exact same Problem even with a non jailbreaked iPhone and it worked after I installed 10.8 on my Macbook Pro. I don't know if that is an option for you but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, Somehow the "Show Disassembly when debugging" was enabled in my Xcode which creates that problem. When I disabled it, all my debugger stopped in my source code.

You can find it under Product->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly when debugging